# Is PHPmailer from github only used for your local host?

Tags: php, html

My PHPmailer from Github does work on my local host but not on my Firebase hosted website. When I submit on my website it downloads the file. Now how to solve it? Do I have to put some extra code in? Someone experienced with Firebase?

```
<?php

// get variables from the form
$name =  $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try{
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                       // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                       // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'example@gmail.com';                  // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '°°°°°°°';                            // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'TLS';                                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    // Sender
    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
    // Recipients
    $mail->addAddress('example@gmail.com', 'Luk Ramon');                           // Add a recipient

    // Body content

    $body = "<p>You received an email from your website <br>name:<strong>".$name." </strong><br>subject: <strong>".$subject."</strong><br>message:<br><i>".$message."</i></p> Contact back on ".$email;

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                        // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Company-name message from '.$name;

    $mail->Body    = $body;
    $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($body);

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase hosting does not support PHP which is why the file is being downloaded.

You'd need to write this in Javascript to use with Firebase - https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions